# I installed VirtualBox 3.1.0 and my wireless interfaces disappeared. How do I get them back?

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking, virtualbox

I'm running VirtualBox 3.1.0 on a Windows XP host with an Ubuntu guest.  I have a Lenovo T60 laptop which uses an Intel Pro/1000 PL network card.  My wireless interfaces disappeared.  They don't even show up in Device Manager.

I have tried uninstalling VirtualBox but I still don't have any wireless interfaces. I have tried installing other versions from 3.0.2 - 3.0.12 without success.  I have tried disabled and renabling the devices in Device Manager without success.

Any ideas on what else I can try?

Comment: State your exact operating system and retag your question, please.  Also edit to mention the specific hardware.

Answer (score 1):

I uninstalled Virtualbox. Then I went into Device Manager and uninstalled my Intel Pro/1000 PL and Intel Pro/Wireless 3495ABG devices. Then I rebooted. Plug and Play reinstalled them and everything came back. I can connect and I can see my network interfaces in Device Manager again.

I also got VirtualBox 3.1.0 to work.  See this thread for additional info:
http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=25451&start=0